# CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton has focus but does not let me edit the contents

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc

I have a `CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton` in my dialog. The issue is that I am not able to edit the text field of the combo box by selecting it. I know the box has focus, and I know it is hitting the piece of code where I do a `SetText` to confirm it.

I also do a `EnableWindow(true)` before that.

However, when I try and edit the box manually, it does not allow me to. No user input is possible on the box. Some other times, the edit window only gets activated if I actually click on the drop down button. I am not setting the `EnableWindow()` to `FALSE`anywhere.

What could be the likely cause?

Comment: A regular combo box can have two different styles, one that lets you enter your own text and one that only lets you select from a dropdown. I would assume a `CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton` would be the same - check the styles you've set when you create it.

Comment: The style given is `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST`. The problem is the disabling of the edit happens only sometimes. The other times I am able to focus and edit. When the edit is disabled, I see the cursor, and it accepts characters like ',' , '[', etc, but not Alphabets or numbers. This is the other weird thing.

Comment: According to Combo Box Styles (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), "CBS_DROPDOWNLIST ...the edit control is replaced by a static text item that displays the current selection in the list box."
Are you modifying the style at run time? Or create an overlay edit control?